# Встраивание изображения

Tags: php, html, base64

Есть скрипт *graph.php*, который создаёт график по характеристикам.

Мне нужно добавить его на страницу, через тег `img` как `src="data:'Content-type';base64`. Проблема в том, что скрипт:

```
<?php
$graph = base64_encode(file_get_contents("graph.php"));
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$graph.'" width="'.$w.'" 
height="'.$h." alt="">';
?>
```

не выводит изображение. Хотя если сохранить результат *graph.php* как *graph.jpeg* на FTP и вместо "graph.php" в **file_get_contents** указать "graph.jpeg", то всё работает.

Вторым способом сам хотел построить этот график, нарисовав его в php-странице, но, можно получить **base64_encode** по идентификатору изображения?

Вариант:
`<img src="graph.php" alt="">` не подходит.

Comment: Минуту, `file_get_contents("graph.php")` получит содерижимое (текст) PHP файла, а не рузельтат его выполнения. Потому и не работает.

Comment: @ilyaplot Спасибо. Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: Да, напишу ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_get_contents` получает содержимое файла, а не результат выполнения скрипта.

Должно работать вот так:

```php
<?php 
$h = 100; 
$w = 100; 
ob_start(); 
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100); 
$white = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255); 
imagefill($image,0,0,$white); 
imagejpeg($image); 
$rawImage = ob_get_clean(); 
$graph = base64_encode($rawImage); 
?> 
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?=$graph?>" width="<?=$w?>" height="<?=$h?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53505/discussion-on-answer-by-ilyaplot--).

Answer (score 1):

Самое банальное - подключить этот файл через `require` с включенной буферизацией вывода

```
ob_start();
require "graph.php";
$data = ob_get_clean();
$graph = base64_encode($data);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$graph.'" width="'.$w.'" 
height="'.$h." alt="">';
```

Comment: Вы чуть чуть опоздали, но один в один :)

Comment: Увы:
Warning: require(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in *** on line ***